# ¿Cómo Implementar un Atajo dentro de un JTextField en Java?

Tags: java, jtextfield, atajo

Tengo un `JTextField` el cual quiero usar el atajo `ctrl + h` para abrir un formulario.
Anteriormente solo he utilizado el siguiente código para el Enter

```
if(evt.getKeyCode() == EventKey.VK_Enter){
   System.out.println("Enter");
 }
```

Pero la idea es utilizar una combinación de Teclas como atajo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo podrías hacer únicamente con la interfaz `KeyListener`, pero puedes usar alternativamente la interfaz `Keymap` que es una colección de teclas vinculadas a acciones.

El detalle es que <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> puede chocar con combinaciones de teclas pre-establecidas para borrado dependiendo del Sistema Operativo, por eso de entrada te recomiendo usar otra combinación como por ejemplo <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (por Formulario):

```
KeyStroke CtrlF = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F, InputEvent.CTRL_MASK); // La combinación de teclas
Action accion = new AbstractAction(){  // Accion a ejecutar
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Control + F");
    }            
};

Keymap myKeymap = JTextComponent.addKeymap("CtrlF", jTextField1.getKeymap()); // Nuevo mapa relacionado al original
myKeymap.addActionForKeyStroke(CtrlF, accion); // Agregamos la combinación de teclas ligada a la acción
jTextField1.setKeymap(myKeymap);
```

Básicamente el truco consiste en crear un nuevo Keymap dentro de la jerarquía usando como ancestro el mapa predeterminado del componente y así no perder los atajos predefinidos como *Copiar* y *Pegar*.

`KeyStroke` es una abstracción de alto nivel de una acción en un dispositivo de entrada, aunque actualmente unicamente esta soportado el teclado.
`KeyStroke` puede ocultar la complejidad de los `KeyEvent`s (Pressed, Typed, Released) con la ventaja de poder incluir combinaciones (modificadores) de tecla como <kbd>ALT</kbd>, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> y <kbd>CTRL</kbd>.

Predeterminadamente, un `JTextComponent` -o subclase- tiene un `Keymap` creado normalmente desde la implementación del *Look And Feel*, 
el cual debería incluir por lo menos el manejo de las acciones para Insertar, Borrar y Mover el cursor dentro del *Editor del Componente*.
Dicho `DEFAULT_KEYMAP` es una sola instancia compartida con todas las instancias de `JTextComponent`.

Antes que usar `KeyListener`, la recomendación es usar *Key Bindings*, que es el sistema de eventos sucesor a `Keymap` y es basado en `InputMap`s y `ActionMap`s; `Keymap` no es nada nuevo, pero fue re-implementado usando el nuevo sistema. Sin embargo, en algunos casos sigue siendo conveniente usar técnicas anteriores.

Comment: Pudieras explicarme un poco los conceptos de `KeyStroke` y `KeyMap` para poder comprender mejor que es lo que realizan.